# Toolbar Size does not adjust when in Landscape Mode

Tags: ios5, xcode4.3, landscape-portrait

I have a toolbar at the bottom of this ViewController. For some reason the toolbar does not want to adjust when the view is rotated to the Landscape Position. I have seen a number of apps with a toolbar at the bottom and when it is rotated it resizes to the equivalent size as the navigation bar! Please help if anyone knows how to do this? I already tried the Size Inspector pane but it does not work.

THANKS!

PORTRAIT VIEW:

[image]

LANDSCAPE VIEW:

[image]